# Is there a way to change the default SQLITE database location on an android phone, to a folder on an HPH website?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, web, location

I have an app that stores a sqlite database in the usual place. ie: data/data/com.blah.blah/databases. I wish to remotely locate the **SQLITE** database and read from and write to it. I wonder if there is a way to do it without using the Oracle Mysql option. Is there a way to just change the default location to a folder on a website. Thanks in advance. If so how do I do it. I cant find any tuts or books that explain how its done.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. I resorted to using PHP -> MYSQL -> JSON to communicate with web DB

Comment: yea Im working the MYSQL option right now. seems there should be a simpler way to store a database that does not contain sensitive data. Its just a file, whats the big deal. Does oracle have the whole web based database market sewn up. Thanks Tony

Comment: @lastshadowrider There are a lot of options not just MySQL. Postgresql, SQL Server, etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems Also, you probably don't want to directly connect to a database through an app because your database connection could possibly be hacked by your app's users. A web service is usually the best option for communication with apps to a central database.

Comment: @lastshadowrider Also, the big deal about the database file on a remote server has several problems.  First, concurrency is an issue if you have multiple users of an app accessing the same database file. Changes from one user would be overwritten by another user. A more advanced database server allows for your data to remain consistent with concurrent usage.  Another problem is network latency. If you did use sqlite to access a remote file all operations would be very slow because a query might touch a lot of places in the file and you might be transferring your entire database for each query.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite isn't a remote database implementation.  That is kind-of part-of white it is called SQ*Lite*. :)  It is for doing SQL databases based on local files, without taking the big additional overhead of having some remoteable service protocol sitting between you and the database.

There are all kinds of options for interacting with remote data stores, not just MySQL - PostgreSQL, etc.  You can use whatever of those you want.  You can then have on the device just the client code you need to communicate with the remote data store.  It doesn't make sense for Android to supply any complicated/sophisticated here built-in, though, since exactly what you want is going to depend mostly on what you are using on your back-end server.